# SQL sum based on two group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I had one table

```
ID   | khk | ts
11AH | 10   | 2
11AH | 10   | 2
11AH | 9    | 1
22AH | 5    | 2
22AH | 5    | 3
```

and I need sum(ts) for grouped ID (but only if count id is more than 2) and from this only if grouped khk count is more than 1)

So for id 11AH is sum(ts) = 4 (not 5) and for 22AH nothing, because they are only two.

I try something like this, but its not right

```
select sum(ts),id from table group by id,khk having count(id)>2 and count(khk)>1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0fd923d6ce6b8c4c9778a2145a5c2d9f)

```
select * from
(select id,khk, sum(ts) as ts,(select count(id) from cte1 b where a.id=b.id) as cnt
from cte1 a 
group by id,khk 
having count(*)>1)X where cnt>2
```

OUTPUT:

```
id      khk  ts  cnt
11AH    10   4   3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using window function

```
with cte
(
select id,khk,ts, count(*) over(partition by id order by id) as id_cnt,
count(*) over(partition by khk order by khk) as khk_cnt
) select id,khk,sum(ts)
 where id_cnt>2 and khk_cnt>1
 group by id,khk
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using analytic functions rather than subqueries:

```
select id, khk, sum_ts
from (select t.id, t.khk, sum(ts) as sum_ts,
             count(*) as cnt_id_khk, 
             count(*) over (partition by t.id) as cnt_id
      from t
      group by id, khk 
     ) t
where cnt_id_khk > 1 and cnt_id > 1
```